# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied With Tesseract OCR and Pytesseract

Tags: windows, permissions, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I know this question has been asked a few times here, but a grand total of 0 of the solutions have worked for me. I've tried running it in the command prompt as an admin, I've tried putting the tesseract folder in a different location (desktop and program files), etc.. I am unable to continue with my project until this is fixed. By the way, I am using Windows. Thanks for your help!

Code:

```
import pytesseract, PIL.Image as Image, cv2, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, json, colorama, pyautogui as pg, os

colorama.init(autoreset=True)

# Setting up the tesseract OCR path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Users\\ccher\\OneDrive\\Desktop"                                                                       

print(colorama.Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + 'Program Started')

screenshot = Image.open('screenshot.png')
found_text: str = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot)
```

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccher\OneDrive\Desktop\Bloxflip Data Collection\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    found_text: str = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot)
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ccher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: so your tesseract executable is in the "C:\Users\ccher\OneDrive\Desktop"? BTW: why do you use 'r' before the path string when you escaped backslash?

Comment: I put it there instead of my C Drive because I figured accessing the disk gave it the permissions error and came to stack overflow after putting it on the desktop didn't work. Tbh, I was really just trying everything, thinking that it could be a problem with my path so that's why I did both.